# Full background image slideshow jquery, want to make the last image of the slideshow clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

This might be a newbie question, so forgive me if the answer is obvious. I did a search to avoid re-asking but what I want is very specific, I want to know if its possible to acheive.

I have a background image slide show using the following jquery code. I used the order of the images to make a presentation. The last image, I want it to be clickable. But only the last image.

For an idea, please see what I did so far : http://www.gulfandlevant.co.uk/taki/index09.html

I am using the following plugin: BGSLIDER-INIT.JS

```
/*global $:false */
/*global window: false */

(function(){
  "use strict";


$(function ($) {

//BG SLIDESHOW WITH ZOOM EFFECT
$.mbBgndGallery.buildGallery({
            containment:"body",
            timer:1300,
            effTimer:1300,
            controls:false, //updated in v1.1
            grayScale:false,
            shuffle:false,
            preserveWidth:false,
            preserveTop: true,
            effect:"fade",
//effect:{enter:{transform:"scale("+(1+ Math.random()*2)+")",opacity:0},exit:{transform:"scale("+(Math.random()*2)+")",opacity:0}},

            // If your server allow directory listing you can use:
            // (however this doesn't work locally on your computer)

            //folderPath:"testImage/",

            // else:

             images:[
             "images/bg/01.jpg",
             "images/bg/02.jpg",
            "images/bg/03.jpg",
            "images/bg/04.jpg",
            "images/bg/05.jpg",
            "images/bg/06.jpg",





             ],

            onStart:function(){},
            onPause:function(){},
            onPlay:function(opt){},
            onChange:function(opt,idx){},
            onNext:function(opt){},
            onPrev:function(opt){}
        });



});
// $(function ($)  : ends

})();
//  JSHint wrapper $(function ($)  : ends
```

The last image, image06 I want it to be clickable, what exactly do I have to add to the code to achieve that effect. I want to link it to a section on my page and add a scroll class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the slideshow is setting a background with a div class "mbBgndGallery". The slideshow isn't quite working correctly for me, however I would assume this plugin is simply replacing the img src. So, knowing nothing about the plugin, I would assume you know which image is the last image in the slideshow. In this case it looks like "images/bg/06.jpg"
is the last image. so I would write something like this.

```
 if($('.mbBgndGallery img').attr('src') === 'images/bg/06.jpg') {
     $('.mbBgndGallery').on('click', function() {
         window.location = "someURL.com";
     });
 }
```

Of course this if statement will only occur when the page is loaded. This code should be added directly into the plugin itself, however if you do not know how to do that I would suggest setting an interval that will check each time the image is changed. It looks as though you are changing images every 1300 ms. So set an interval for the same amount of time. with a slight offset.

```
 var i = setInterval(function() {
    if($('.mbBgndGallery img').attr('src') === 'images/bg/06.jpg') {
       $('.mbBgndGallery').on('click', function() {
           window.location = "someURL.com";
       });
    }
 }, 1350);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .click() of jQuery:

```
$('.mbBgndGallery').click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').each(function() {
        if( $(this).attr('src') == 'images/bg/06.jpg' )
            DO CLICK STUFF
    });
});
```